# Detect keyboard and mouse events when not on browser tab

Tags: mouseevent, next.js13, keyboard-events, navigator

I am building an web app in **nextj**s which capture **screenshots** of users who are working on a project (like upwork) where i want to calculate idle time of user. For this to work i want to detect the time for which keyboard and mouse are inactive. I can detect if key is pressed or not from keyboard and mouse action but when i switch from chrome to another window like **VS Code** or file explorer i can't detect keyboar or mouse event.

How can I detect keyboard and mouse event even when user is not using on chrome or any browser?

Alredy tried navigator.keyboard API but it will only detect when app is opned in chrome tab?